# Stop UItableView scrolling From its Cell

Tags: swift

I had to disable scrolling when cell trigger action of table view start, then i want to enable scrolling again.
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You could probably keep track of the table view scroll position with the scroll view delegate. The non did select item you could set the scroll position of the tableview to the current position and disable scrolling in the tableview.

Comment: Yes it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should stop your scrolling abruptly:

```
tableView.setContentOffset(_ contentOffset: tableView.contentOffset, animated: false)
```

To generally disable scrolling in the tableView for the user:

```
tableView.isScrollEnabled= false
```

... to enable again:

```
tableView.isScrollEnabled= true
```

[Take a look here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619395-isscrollenabled)